# Call c# function in compiled .exe from cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

Is there a direct/straightforward way to use Command Prompt (cmd) to call a function that's in a compiled c# project (in .exe).

I know I can write code that makes the project accepts string arguments, and then check them to call the function that the user needs to run.

But I'm asking if there's a more direct/straight-forward way to call functions from a compiled .exe c# file.

Comment: Probably using PowerShell.

Comment: Is there a cmd alternative?

Comment: You could make a utility that lets you specify the DLL, static type name, static method name, and arguments. And then you could call it to interact with any .NET DLL. This is beginning to feel like an XY problem if PowerShell isn't an option. What are you trying to achieve that requires you to do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Methods are not just a piece of code you call, exe-file is not a DLL with export table.

Comment: I'm trying to use Autohotkey to run specific c# functions. So I have my functions compiled each in a separate .exe file to be able to run from cmd by defining file name of the function I want to run. I need to combine my many growing functions in one .exe file and be able to call them from cmd selectively. Unfortunately Autohotkey has a lot of issues running Powershell commands on Windows 10.

Comment: A dll and an exe are the same except a exe has a main so it can be started directly from windows.  So you can call public methods in a exe (just like a dll) from another c# application.

Comment: Judging from your post and your comment, I think the correct way to go for you is to create a CLI, either from scratch or by using a framework like [CliFx](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** It is not possible to call a C# method directly from CMD

---

**Longer answer**: It is however possible to do it from PowerShell and use reflection to load and execute it. Something along the lines of

```
// or ::LoadFrom("..\relative\path")
$lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\path\to\file.exe")
$obj = new-object MyClass
$result = $obj.MyMethod("my", "parameters", "3)
```

CMD cannot do this, as it cannot interface with .NET Assemblies itself. It whoever is possible to create a utility that you could use from CMD in C# to do it for you.

But my recommendation is, if you really need to call it from CMD or PowerShell or wherever, is to use a framework like [CliFx](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx) to create a command line interface for your application